# Error launching 'roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch': Not a package or launch file name. Using Ubuntu 12.04 and Groovy. New to ROS and Kinect

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

openni_lauch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65363/when-i-typed-%27roslaunch-openni_launch-openni.launch%27-it-says-is-not-a-package-or-launch-file-name.i%27m-using-ubuntu-12.04-and-groovy.-i%27m-new-to-ros-and-kinect.-can-somebody-help?/) by [Cham](https://answers.ros.org/users/5147/cham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cham](https://answers.ros.org/users/5147/cham/) on 2013-06-20**:
Yeah I did. Somehow it works now. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you installed it completely via sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-openni-launch? It sometimes produces errors

---

Originally posted by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) with karma: 141 on 2013-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2